# PHP: Using a Phing Task in Composer Package

Tags: php, build, composer-php, phing

I've created a Composer package, and in it I have defined a custom Phing Task that extends Task. In my project that includes the Composer package, I want to be able to use this Phing task in my build file but I keep getting this error:

```
   [taskdef] Error importing generateViews\GenerateView.php
[PHP Error] include_once(generateViews\GenerateView.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [line 1058 of C:\Users\Me\Downloads\phing-2.4.13\classes\phing\Phing.php]

[PHP Error] include_once(): Failed opening 'generateViews\GenerateView.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\Users\Me\Downloads\phing-2.4.13\bin/../classes;.;C:\php\pear') [line 1058 of C:\Users\Me\Downloads\phing-2.4.13\classes\phing\Phing.php]
BUILD FAILED
Error reading project file [wrapped: Error importing generateViews\GenerateView.php]
Total time: 0.1742 seconds



Build finished at 6/28/2015 8:35 PM with exit code 0.
```

Here's my build file trying to use the "generateview" task:

```
<taskdef name="generateview" classname="generateViews.GenerateView" />

 <target name="viewgenerator" >
    <echo msg="Generating View: ${absname}" />
    <generateview name="${absname}"/>
</target>
```

Here's my actual task:

```
namespace tasks\generateViews;

class GenerateView extends \Task {
```

And here's my autoload section of composer.json. This is the part I'm really not sure about.

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-0": {
    "MyProject": "src/",
    "tasks": "src/tasks",
    "generateViews": "src/tasks/generateViews"
  }
}
```

In case it helps, my project structure is as follows:

```
MyProject
   src
      tasks
         generateViews
      otherStuff
         view
   tests
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.

I needed to add this to my build file:

```
<php expression="include('vendor/autoload.php')"/>
```

And I added GenerateView.php file to autoload classmap like:

```
   "classmap": ["src/tasks/generateViews/GenerateView.php"],
```

Comment: I'd say that this is a very tangled and obscure dependency. I would use Phing and Composer as globally installed tools that either have no other dependencies, or have them installed and ready to use. The build file of any project should always be usable without the need to install more dependencies. For example, "phing test" should run all tests, and these usually need installed libraries, so would run `composer install` as a dependent sub task. This should not fail because the build file cannot load the generateViews task files.